# Best way to access models children in ember

Tags: ember.js

What is the best/right way to access a model's children in a route?

Route Code:

```
this.store.find('Parent', params.parent_id).then(function(parent){
   //this works
   var a = parent._data.children.length;
   //this doesn't but feels like it should?
   var a = parent.get('children').length;
})
```

Model:

```
App.Parent = DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    children: DS.hasMany('child', {async: true}),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = parent.get('children').length;
```

Is probably returning a promise. You can check this by doing a `console.log('children', parent.get('children')`. You can resolve this promise before checking the length by:

```
var a;
parent.get('children').then(function (children) {
  // Children promise has been resolved
  a = children.length;
});
```